# Cannot call a function-like procedural macro: cannot be expanded to statements

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to get my head around function-like procedural macros and struggling with the basics.

For a starter, I tried to create a macro that just prints all the tokens and does nothing:

```
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate syn;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    println!( "{:?}", input );

    TokenStream::new()
}
```

I then tried to use it in another binary:

```
extern crate rust_procmacro_test;

fn main() {
    rust_procmacro_test::my_macro!( aaa );
}
```

When I do `cargo build` I get this:

```
Compiling rust_procmacro_test v0.1.0 
Compiling procmacro_user v0.1.0 
error[E0658]: procedural macros cannot be expanded to statements (see issue #54727)
 --> src\main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     rust_procmacro_test::my_macro!( aaa );
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TokenStream [Ident { ident: "aaa", span: #0 bytes(114..117) }]
error: aborting due to previous error
```

It tells me that this cannot be compiled, but `println` inside the macro works. What is happening?

[Issue #54727](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54727) is very broad and I'm not sure how it relates to this.

I'm using stable-i686-pc-windows-gnu, rustc 1.31.1 (b6c32da9b 2018-12-18).

Comment: Quick question: Why do you develop for `i686`? No one should do that anymore... It is superseded by `x86_64`.

Comment: @hellow because there is no 64-bit gcc compiler for windows and so there is no x86_64-pc-windows-gnu target (that I'm aware of) and I had difficulties debugging with x86_64-windows-msvc.

Comment: `rustup target list` will give you `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` and `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` :) [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707118/how-to-debug-rust-unit-tests-on-windows) a good question about visual debugging rust

Comment: @hellow hmm, I guess you're right, my knowledge is outdated :) I'll look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is happening?

While it's possible to *define* a function-like procedural macro in stable Rust, it's not yet possible to *call* one as an expression / statement. This is because there are [concerns about how *hygiene* should be applied](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/52121#issuecomment-422311424). There are other locations, such as in item position, where it is available:

```
extern crate rust_procmacro_test;

rust_procmacro_test::my_macro!( aaa );

fn main() {}
```

> but `println` inside the macro works

This is probably just some laziness in the implementation — the macro is eagerly evaluated and then the feature gate is checked later. While this might be inefficient at the moment, once the feature is fully stabilized it won't matter.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. Thank you!