# Visual Studio Code Task is Prepending the working directory to the command

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I'm trying to setup visual studio code for rust to do debugging.  In my launch.json file I have

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/vscode-rust-debug-example.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "localcargobuildtask"
        }
    ]
}
```

and in my tasks.json I have

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "localcargobuildtask",
            "command": "echo hi",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }        
    ]
}
```

Where "echo hi" is in my tasks I eventually want to have something like "cargo build" or "cargo test" or whatever.  But this is just a starting step.

But when I press F5 the output I get is

```
> Executing task: C:\programs\VSCodeWorkspaces\RustProjects\vscode-rust-debug-example-debug-config-included\echo hi  <

The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Rather than running "echo" from where ever the terminal finds it (working directory first, then check global path variable like you would expect) it is actually looking for a program named "echo" in my root folder of the workspace.

How do I tell visual studio code "No I don't want you to run workspace/echo, I want you to run echo in workspace" ?  Or is there another more direct way to tell visual studio code "compile this before you debug it" ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question [How to debug Rust unit tests on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707118/how-to-debug-rust-unit-tests-on-windows)
suggests that changing

```
"command": "cargo build",
```

into

```
"command": "cargo",
    "args": [
        "build"
    ],
```

in the tasks.json file works and somehow it does.  Maybe the editor is configured to search the %path% for single word commands, or maybe some plugin I installed overwrote the "cargo" command.  Maybe the reason echo wasn't found is because it is a terminal command, not a program.  Maybe the error message was a lie and it was only reporting that it couldn't find workspacefolder\command despite checking %path%?  Or maybe none of that.  I have no idea.  It is some pretty idiosyncratic behavior.

Comment: I eventually found a bare minimum answer to my question.  If someone finds a more detailed response and can confirm or deny my suspicion that this is a big bug then I will accept that answer instead, thank you.