# How to debug a Rust Integration Test using VSCode + cppdbg

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, debugging, rust, gdb

I want to debug a Rust integration test in VSCode using **gdb** (much better enum support than lldb).
I used to use lldb using the fantastic `CodeLLDB` plugin, where my configuration in `launch.json` looked like this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "run integration test",
            "sourceLanguages": ["rust"],
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--package=name_of_my_package",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--tests",
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "kind": "test"
                }
            },
            "args": [
                "--exact",
                "--nocapture",
                "name_of_my_test",
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        },
    ],
}
```

For using gdb, I assume that I would have to use the `cpptools` extension instead (debug type `"cppdbg"`), which does not support the `"cargo"` directive.

**How can I create an equivalent configuration to the one above for `cpptools`?**

(or some other extension supporting gdb)

The main problem seems to be getting the correct path of the test binary, which contains a nondeterministic hash.
I found nothing better than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707118/how-to-debug-rust-unit-tests-on-windows?rq=4), which is quite old, windows specific, and doesn't have any satisfactory answer. Is there a better solution for this by now?

Worst case, I would not even be opposed to some kind of hack using `tasks.json` to move/symlink the binary to a deterministic location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a hacky way to do it using the `tasks.json` mechanism I alluded to. This requires `jq` and `xargs` on the `PATH`.
The `set -o pipefail;` can be removed if not supported, at the cost of potentially running an outdated binary.

If anybody has a better way, I would gladly accept their answer over this.

`my_package_name` and `my_test_name` obviously have to be adjusted.

---

`tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build_integration_test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "set -o pipefail; cargo test --package=my_package_name --no-run --tests --message-format=json | jq -r 'first(select(.executable != null and .target.kind == [\"test\"])) | .executable' | xargs -I@ ln -fs @ ${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/integration_test_bin",
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

---

`launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
     {
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "debug integration test (cppdbg)",
            "preLaunchTask": "build_integration_test",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/integration_test_bin",
            "args": [  
                "--exact",
                "--nocapture",
                "my_test_name"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        },
    ],
}
```